# Can I encrypt password in java to counteract a website popup?

Tags: java, selenium

I'm running some tests using selenium web driver. There is a popup that occurs before the web page loads up. Asking for the username and password. I obviously don't want to hardcode the password into my code. Is there a way I can hide this in the code like encrypt it so it still runs the test and my password isn't exposed?

I have this code:

```
    @Step
public void gotoSurveyManager(){
    getDriver().get("http://user:password@website.surveymanager.sys.networks.local");

}
```

Comment: Create a Automation test user?

Comment: That would work in principle. Again it's the login used for the network so you can see the flaws in it still.

Comment: Could you store them as environment variables and get them from there when needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you would like to store a encrypted password in your code and the encryption procedure and the key in the same code? This is only obfuscation but no security. Of course you could store the key in a seperate file but you can do so with your password, too.

I don't know your setting and how you start your tests but maybe you could pass the credentials via command line paramters of your test application.

Comment: Ok how would I go about obfuscate that line of code? Is it simple to do?

Comment: Maybe something like Base64.getDecoder().decode("eJwLTk0uSi0BAAgRAmc=") would do the trick. You also could use more advanced algorithms but again, this is NOT secure!